# which one faster, getimeofday or clock_gettime?

Tags: c, linux, datetime, time, system-calls

I want to store event time.
I found these two functions, but don't know which one is faster.

Answer (score 4):

```
int main()
{
    struct timespec tp;
    struct timeval tv;
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    for(i=0; i < 500000; i++)
    {
        gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
        j+= tv.tv_usec%2;
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_HIGHRES, &tp);
        j+=tp.tv_sec%2;
    }
    return 0;

}



 %Time Seconds Cumsecs  #Calls   msec/call  Name
  68.3    0.28    0.28  500000      0.0006  __clock_gettime
  22.0    0.09    0.37  500000      0.0002  _gettimeofday
   7.3    0.03    0.40 1000009      0.0000  _mcount
   2.4    0.01    0.41       1     10.      main
   0.0    0.00    0.41       4      0.      atexit
   0.0    0.00    0.41       1      0.      _exithandle
   0.0    0.00    0.41       1      0.      _fpsetsticky
   0.0    0.00    0.41       1      0.      _profil
   0.0    0.00    0.41       1      0.      exit
```

This ran on Solaris 9 v440 box.  Profile the code on your own box.  This result is completely different from the result quoted in a link supplied earlier.  In other words, if there is a difference it will be due to the implmenetation.

Answer (score 3):

It will depend on your system; there's no standard for which is faster. My guess would be they're usually both about the same speed. `gettimeofday` is more traditional and probably a good bet if you want your code to be portable to older systems. `clock_gettime` has more features.

Comment: For clock_gettime() and the new C23 equivalent, it really depends on what operating system and architecture you're running *and* also which clock you are accessing.  Because they are extremely widely used and thus the first ones that would be optimized for high-frequency access, CLOCK_REALTIME and CLOCK_MONOTONIC are safe choices, for the others, YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on constant, used in `clock_gettime()`. For the fastest clocks, there are `CLOCK_*_COARSE` constants. These timers are fastest, but are not precise.

`gettimeofday()` should return the same as `clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME)`

Also, benchmark results depend on architecture (for Linux). Since Linux has special technology (VDSO) to eliminate syscall to get time. These technologies do not work on X86-32bit architecture. See `strace` output.

Comment: Actually, at least on Linux, some of the clocks are "VDSO-accelerated". Other operating systems might do the same.   And guess what, gettimeofday(), and clock_gettime() for CLOCK_MONOTONIC and CLOCK_REALTIME *are* VDSO-accelerated in pretty much every non-ancient Linux version on all architectures.   This is *not* true for the COARSE clocks, so they can be actually MUCH slower to read!

Answer (score -2):

You don't care.

If you're calling either of them often enough that it matters, You're Doing It Wrong.

Profile code which is causing specific performance problems and check how much time it  is spending in there. If it's too much, consider refactoring it to call the function less often.

Comment: If you answer questions this way, You're Doing It Wrong :-) Maybe he wants to write his own profiler? And the execution time of these functions in itself may affect the result they deliver.

Answer (score -3):

Have a look at this [discussion](http://developerweb.net/viewtopic.php?id=4368).  It seems of good quality and very closely related to what you might be looking for though a little dated.